# Train/Test split for imbalanced regression problem

Tags: multiple-regression, unbalanced-classes, validation

I have a dataset with ~100K samples and continuous target variable which has 95% of zero values.

Since there are high-dimensional categorical features and missing values in my data, I plan to use tree-based models that can handle this well. I know about "zero-inflated" approach where one first classifies the probability of non-zero value and then uses a regression model to predict the magnitude of this value. But I'd like to something simpler / faster to create and train.

So here's my question. If I plan to use one-step prediction with tree-based regression model do I need to bother with splitting the dataset in such a way which preserves 5% of non-zero values in both train and test parts?

EDIT. I'm also considering an idea to add sample weights so that samples with non-zero target value will have weight inversely proportional to their chances of occurrence. Any comments regarding this approach combined with the above-mentioned sampling will be of great help.

Are there any common/recommended approaches to perform/evaluate regression models on such datasets?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The big problem here is going to be model validation, since a model that predicts 0 every time is going to have 95% prediction accuracy. What I have done in the past is for every cross-validation dataset, subsample the 0 values and preserve the 5% non-zero values as you mentioned above. That way, when you train your model it has a better plit of zero to non-zero values, say 20/80 instead of 5/95.

You also may consider using a custom loss function with gradient-boosted trees to give more heavily penalize inaccurate predictions on non-zero values. Lastly, if you are running into insufficient non-zero training/testing data you could consider replicating the non-zero rows 5, 10, or 20 times to have them picked up in the model at the expense of overfitting with regard to those rows.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with your test set. Your test set should ideally preserve your population's properties and value prevalence. Thus taking a random say 20% sample from your 100K should work fine. For assessing your model's accuracy you can introduce your own loss functions. Usually, for imbalanced datasets we care more for the non-zero values. Thus, you can introduce your own custom loss functions. For instance, you can calculate the MSE only in the cases when the model predicts a value above $\alpha$.

The training dataset now, should ideally become more balanced as this seems to work better empirically. Hence, I would look into doing some re-sampling techniques such as undersampling, oversampling and SMOTE (These are usually used for classification but you can extend it and use it for your case as well. Have a look at SMOTE, it might work well in your case). Your approach with sample weights based on value sparsity makes sense to me as well. Again, the purpose of all these is to make your training test a bit more balanced so that your model is better at predicting. If I were you, however, I would spend more time/energy to create a robust loss/utility function that makes sense for the project under consideration.